# Quantum volume calculation: what is the significance of the value 2/3 for probability to observe a heavy output in the definition of achievable depth?

Tags: quantum-algorithms, quantum-volume

I am looking into the algorithm to calculate the quantum volume of a given quantum computer. The one thing that is unclear to me is how the achievable depth is defined.

In [Andrew W. Cross, Lev S. Bishop, Sarah Sheldon, Paul D. Nation, and Jay M. Gambetta
Phys. Rev. A 100, 032328 (2019)](https://journals.aps.org/pra/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevA.100.032328) [[arXiv:1811.12926](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1811.12926.pdf)], they write:

> *We define the achievable depth $d(m)$ to be the largest $d$ such that we are confident $h_d > 2/3$.*

Where $h_d$ is the probability of observing a heavy output by
implementing a randomly selected depth $d$ model circuit.

Where does the value $2/3$ come from? Why does one take $2/3$? And not, e.g. $3/4$? Is it an arbitrary choice, or is there statistical meaning to it?

Comment: At least [this blog post](https://scottaaronson.blog/?p=4649) by Aaronson suggests 2/3 is arbitrary.  But also, when we define certain complexity classes such as [BQP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BQP) or QMA we like to use ">2/3" and "<1/3" as the completeness/soundness bounds - amplification by repetition can always be used to reduce this to 99.9999% and 0.00001%, for example.